# Team Foundation Server 2010 and Sharepoint/WSS3.0

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, team-foundation-server

As I'm new to Team Foundation Server, this may seem a bit of a daft question but I have been tasked with installing TFS2010.

What I want to know is, do I have to have a full version of MOSS 2007 installed to build a project dashboard for TFS or can I get away with just using WSS 3.0 that comes with TFS?

Having looked through the docs for TFS, I get the idea that I have to have a full Sharepoint installation somewhere. Though I'd like this to be clarified if possible.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you can use TFS2010 without SharePoint.

According to the [TFS2010 Install Guide](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?displaylang=en&FamilyID=2d531219-2c39-4c69-88ef-f5ae6ac18c9f), WSS3/MOSS2007 is supported, in fact that is what the guide lists (MOSS2010 is not listed).

Comment: Oh I know I can use it without, but for the dashboards with the graphs such as http://blogs.msdn.com/blogfiles/aaronbjork/WindowsLiveWriter/HowdoesMSFAgile4.2comparetoMSFAgile5.0_62AD/Quality1.png, do I definately need to have MOSS installed?

Comment: @Liam: Those dashboards make use of SharePoint and SQL Server Analysis/Reporting. Whether WSS is sufficient is unclear (I would think it would be in most cases, but you may have to try it yourself if you cannot find a definite answer).